# The negation of $\exists x \forall y \neg \forall z(P(x,y) \iff Q(x,y) \land R(x,y,z))$

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand the negation of
$\exists x \forall y \neg \forall z(P(x,y) \iff Q(x,y) \land R(x,y,z))$

As a side example if I have a statement
$\neg \forall x P(x)$, then this is equivalent to $\exists x \neg P(x)$ where the negation is $\forall x P(x)$, motivating what I think is the answer to my overall question.

Then I believe the answer should be:
$\forall x \exists y \forall z(P(x,y) \iff Q(x,y) \land R(x,y,z))$ (i.e simply remove the $\neg$ from the $\forall z$)

but I am a bit paranoid that the answer could be:
$\forall x \exists y \forall z(P(x,y) \iff \neg Q(x,y) \lor \neg R(x,y,z))$, passing the negation through to the inner bracket.

Any insights which is correct appreciated.

Comment: Please replace one quantifier's $x$ with $z$ in both the original statement and each attempt you make to negate it.

Comment: @J.G. done, whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial feeling is right:$$\neg\exists x\forall y\neg\forall z\phi(x,\,y,\,z)\iff\forall x\neg\forall y\neg\forall z\phi(x,\,y,\,z)\iff\forall x\exists y\forall z\phi(x,\,y,\,z).$$Alternatively,$$\neg\exists x\forall y\neg\forall z\phi(x,\,y,\,z)\iff\neg\exists x\neg\exists y\exists z\phi(x,\,y,\,z)\iff\forall x\exists y\forall z\phi(x,\,y,\,z).$$

Answer (score 1):

[Your  initial  answer  is right](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%C2%AC(%E2%88%83x%E2%88%80y%C2%AC%E2%88%80z(Pxy%20%E2%86%94%20(Qxy%20%E2%88%A7%20R(x,y,z))))%E2%86%94%20%E2%88%80x%E2%88%83y%E2%88%80z(Pxy%20%E2%86%94%20(Qxy%20%E2%88%A7%20R(x,y,z))))

The tool in the link is the most helpful thing I have found for such problems.